# How to implement 2 classes with similar behavior of their methods

Tags: c++, inheritance

If I have two classes with similar behavior but different returned value, what is the best way to implement it?

For example:

```
class A{
   int method1( int a, int b ){ ... do something...}
}
class B{
   float method1( int a, int b ){ ... do the same stuff as in class A...}
}
```

The only thing that I can think about is to implement all the significant code in a third class C, inherit from it and to write wrappers in classes A and B accordingly to their returned values.

Is there some better way to do it?

Comment: A free-function function template?

Comment: It'll be hard to give advice that's really general and not specific to this one example. If you're planning on using this for multiple purposes, it would be a good idea to give a bit more context on those in order to have a solution that works for all of them.

Comment: The "all the significant code in a third class C and inherit from it" is also called a [mixin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin)

Comment: Classes don't have behavior and they don't return values. They have member functions that do those things. But there's nothing in the question as currently written that requires using member functions; as @Niall suggested, free functions are sufficient in the absence of further requirements.

Comment: Oh, you mean to say `vector` and `map` should have named `size` method differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach would be possible using CRTP idiom:

```
template<typename T>
struct C {
    auto method1( int a, int b ){
        return static_cast<T*>(this)->method1Impl(a, b);
    }
};

struct A: C<A> {
    int method1Impl( int a, int b ) { return 42; }
};

struct B: C<B> {
    float method1Impl( int a, int b ) { return .0; }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;

    a.method1(0, 0);
    b.method1(0, 0);
}
```

Note that this solution works if you can use C++14.

Comment: Thank you, it would be a good solution but unfortunatly I can only use C++11.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by making B a child of A, (inheritance) this would look as follows (let's say we make an addition to demonstrate):

```
class A {
public:
    int method1(int a, int b) {
        return a + b; // your implementation here 
    }
};
```

Note that method1 in A must be public or protected (not private) so that B, the child can access it.

```
class B : A // Declare that B extends A
{
public:
    float method1(int a, int b){
        return A::method1(a, b); // access method1 from A
    };
};
```

Now you can use the same method in A and in B with different return types.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why not:

```
namespace 
{
  commonFunc(int a, int b) { do common stuff}
}

class A{
   int method1( int a, int b ){ commonFunc(a,b);}
}
class B{
   float method1( int a, int b ){ commonFunc(a,b);}
}
```

This requires a bit more work if the common functions are directly manipulating member variables, but it seems the simplest solution.